# How Can I make sure a file can be downloaded only if the user is logged in? ( no forms authentication )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some files I make available to the logged user to download, those ones can't be available if there is nobody logged in.

I check if the user is on of off by one session, Session["User"] for example

I am not using forms authentication.

any tips are valid, even you don't think it is the final solution, thanks

Comment: What about using windows auth or a custom authentication?

Comment: Couldn't you simply check Session to see if User has a value - if there's a value for User, they're logged on.  Not exactly sure what it is you're looking for.

Comment: _I am not using forms authentication_ - then what does "logged in" mean in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the available using response/streaming instead a link to an actual file.
Something as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net). Based on the logged user you can add it to the page, or not.

Comment: it looks that is what I am looking for, I'm checking it now