# ASP MVC open a live stream between remote host and the connected user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, header, stream

The idea is simple, i am creating a service where user can put the direct link of a file that is being hosted on another website and my program will open a stream to that remote server and start reading the file in bytes and then return each readed byte to the user.

Example :
Internet download manager will go to my page, then my code will fetch the remote file and read it in bytes and return each byte to Internet download manager to download the file.

here is my code

```
    public void Index()
    {
        using (WebClient wcDownload = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a request to the file we are downloading
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://FILE-IS-NOT-ON-MY-SERVER.com/file.zip");
                // Set default authentication for retrieving the file
                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // Retrieve the response from the server
                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                // Ask the server for the file size and store it
                Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

                // Open the URL for download 
                Stream strResponse = wcDownload.OpenRead("http://FILE-IS-NOT-ON-MY-SERVER.com/file.zip");

                // It will store the current number of bytes we retrieved from the server
                int bytesSize = 0;
                // A buffer for storing and writing the data retrieved from the server
                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[500000000];


                // Loop through the buffer until the buffer is empty
                while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    // i want to return each byte to the user for example Internet Download Manager
                }


                // When the above code has ended, close the streams
                strResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

i know it is messy but i really don't know how to return each byte to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you want to obtain a stream from the requested response, then assign that stream to your response stream (or write into your response stream).

I think *[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)* has a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406 can help you a lot! All you need is change the file open for your download.