# How to open save as dialog box for downloading from cloud

Tags: azure, save, cloud, download, filestream

I'm making project which includes downloading files from cloud(Azure) storage. I want to open save as dialog box but not getting it . I used following code.

```
enter code here // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob1");
        string FileName = "a3.jpg";
        string Filename = FileName.Substring(0, FileName.LastIndexOf("."));``
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" FileName);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/blockBlob/myblob1/" + Filename));
        Response.End();

        /* to download file from cloud
```

using(var fileStream =System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\prak\Pictures\ppp.JPG"))
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
                Response.Write("
");
                Response.Write("Succefully downloaded!");
            }*/

please help...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect your form to an ashx handler that writes the file content directly into the output stream. This is not specific to Azure, although if the file is being accessed from a blob it may need to be moved temporarily to the web server so you can reference the local path in the "attachment;filename".

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"myfile.jpg\"" );
// write file data to output stream here
Response.End();
```

Another method is to use `HttpWebRequest` as described in the following post:

[Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)

Comment: sorry....it isn't working.....actually an empty file gets transferred.... I used following code :                                         Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = p;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +p);*/
            // write file data to output stream here
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite( @"C:\Users\public\desktop\"+p))
            { blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);}

            Response.End();