# FileWebRequest not returning what it should

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to send a file from my machine to the browser, so that it can be downloaded, in a .NET application I am working on. I am using the code in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605490/1546713) SO answer, but instead of using an HttpWebRequest I am using a FileWebRequest because I am accessing the file on my local machine. The request looks like this:
`FileWebRequest fileReq = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"file:///C:/Tmp/new.html");` and when I copy the url `file:///C:/Tmp/new.html` into the browser, it gives me the correct file. But when I use `fileReq.ContentLength` in my code it always returns `0`, which leads me to believe that the file is not being read for some reason. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

**EDIT:** Here's my code, like I said exactly like from the other SO question, but I used FileWebRequest instead of HttpWebRequest.

```
        Stream stream = null;
        int bytesToRead = 10000;
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
        try
        {               
            FileWebRequest fileReq = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"file:///C:/Tmp/new.html");
            FileWebResponse fileResp = (FileWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

            if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;
                stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
                var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                resp.AddHeader("Content-dsiposition", "attachment; filename=" + url);
                resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

                int length;
                do
                {
                    if (resp.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                        resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        resp.Flush();
                        buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        length = -1;
                    }
                } while (length > 0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FileLabel.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Provide the actual code you have written.

Comment: Why don't you just open the file and feed it into the response? Why "open" it with a request/response pair? Have you considered Response.TransmitFile?

Comment: @Alexander this sounds like what I want to do, could you elaborate on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try WebClient class.

```
 public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
    }
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    // Add a user agent header in case the 
    // requested URI contains a query.

    client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    Console.WriteLine (s);
    data.Close ();
    reader.Close ();
```

[tutorial here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient)

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.110).aspx
This method just accepts the file path and does the rest for you.

Comment: how do I get the HttpResponse object?

Comment: Like you do in your own code. Or just use the Page's Response.

Comment: ok, that puts the contents of the file on that actual page. I want the user to be able to download the actual file, but I feel like I'm getting close.