# Download large files from website

Tags: asp.net, streaming, large-files

I think this question is repeated in many places. But I would like to know the better solution which won't give overhead to server.

My scenario is like a user should be able to click on a link in website and that link will get the correct file from server and send it to user.

I see solutions like below,

```
string filename1 = "newfile.txt";
string filename = @"E:\myfolder\test.txt";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename1 + "\"");
Response.TransmitFile(filename);
```

and like in below post,

[Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)

Comment: What have you tried and how is it not working?  What do you mean by "the better solution which won't give overhead to server"?  If you link to a file, clicking that link will generally download that file.

Comment: MVC is part ASP.NET. Perhaps you mean you're using Web Forms instead of MVC. And it's hard to know what overhead you have if you're not showing us how you're obtaining the files and sending them to the client.

Comment: I've edited the question, both the solutions are working in a dev server. But I'm wondering which one will perform better in production environment when multiple users download the files and the file size is large.

Comment: @blue You'll need to do your own testing to determine which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences I spotted between the 2 methods you mention is:
1. Uses `Response.TransmitFile`
2. Uses `Response.WriteFile`

In order to compare the two methods you should look at these links:

[TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.110).aspx)
*Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream, without buffering it in memory.*

[WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx)
*Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream.*

Clearly, `Response.TransmitFile()` sends the file to the client machine without loading it to the Application memory on the server, but `Response.WriteFile()` method loads the file that is being downloaded in the Application memory area of the server.

I would say use `Response.TransmitFile()` for larger files based on this alone.

However, you will need to look into how this impacts other parts of your application before you make a final decision.

This has been pretty comprehensively debated on various forums. Look for it.