# Unexpected behavior on downloading generated Excel file via MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to generate and download an Excel file with ASP.NET MVC 4.

The file generation works fine, but the download have a behavior that I don't understand.

When I click on my download button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("DOWNLOAD", "Download", "Session", new { sessionId = Model.Session.Id, clientId = Model.Client.Id }, new { @class = "my-link" })
```

The excel file open with the right content, but it is saved at `D:\data\documents\System.IO.MemoryStream` which is not my default download directory.

And a empty file is saved at `D:\downloads\infos.xls`, which is my default download directory.

```
Directory D:\downloads

18/07/2016  05:10    <DIR>          .
18/07/2016  05:10    <DIR>          ..
18/07/2016  05:10                 0 infos.xls
           1 file(s)                0 octets


Directory D:\data\documents

18/07/2016  05:10    <DIR>          .
18/07/2016  05:10    <DIR>          ..
18/07/2016  05:10             8 521 System.IO.MemoryStream
           1 file(s)                8 521 octets
```

Here is my controller method:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

[Authorize]
public class SessionController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Download(int sessionId, int clientId)
    {
        /* [...] Retreive infos */
        
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
    
        /* [...]  Insert infos in worksheet */

        byte[] data;

        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            data = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "infos.xls");
    }
}
```

Why are there are two downloaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because that the function is misused. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195820.aspx):

> Worksheet.SaveAs Method (Excel)
>
> Saves changes to the chart or worksheet in a different file.

The input requires a **file name**, but you put in **a stream object**.

```
workbook.SaveAs(stream);
```

That is why the strange file is created in your default user folder.

To understand why the empty file is created, check this code:

```
return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "infos.xls");
```

Here an empty stream is returned (the stream data is never set), with the name of infos.xls

To perform a file download, you can check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net).

Comment: Thanks you. 
I didn't noticed that the examples I saw used another libraries.
I switched from Microsoft Interop to EPPlus and it works fine, now i can save the file in a MemoryStream.