# Streaming a file from Controller to View for user to download

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor

I am looking to Stream a file from an internally generated URL(i.e http://192.168.x.x/download/filekeylink) to a user to download. The way I have it set up is the user hits the download button which sends a WEBAPI POST request to the controller which then hits an API that gets the URL with the file ready. The problem here is while I have experience loading local files from paths, I haven't ever streamed a file from a URL before and I was told this is possibly better than storing it in memory(can't store it locally)

js

```
async downloadAttach(ID: any) {
    
    window.open(await ApiFunc.post('Ticket', 'Download', CommID));// my own API call fucntion that works. 

    
}
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/Ticket/Download")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<//Streamed file> Download([FromBody]string uri)
        {
            //Returning the streamed file to user to download
        }
```

What is the best practice around this(avoiding storing file locally or storing it in memory first). I have seen some people using

```
HttpWebRequest
```

However I am unsure that fits my needs as it seems this utilises the need to access the internal url(I could be wrong but when I tried it, it failed.)

For example this code here by Dallas:

[Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)

I'm trying to understand how this would return to the client view and start the download in their browser without a return value. Is it because instead it would be using a GET API?

Comment: Have you found a solution or are you or anyone else still looking for a solution ?